# easy_install will not connect through proxy

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, proxy, python, easy-install

I'm running Ubuntu Server 10.04 64-bit under VirtualBox, and it seems that everything *except* easy_install and pip can connect to the Internet.  I have set and exported the http_proxy environment variable, and also set up the proxy address in every other location I'm aware of.  Yet easy_install always returns "Network is unreachable":

```
:~$ echo $http_proxy
http://192.168.1.25:80/

:~$ grep "http_proxy" /etc/bash.bashrc
export http_proxy=http://192.168.1.25:80/

:~$ grep "http_proxy" /etc/wgetrc
http_proxy = http://192.168.1.25:80/

:~$ ping pypi.python.org
PING pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=114 ms
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=113 ms
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=113 ms
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=113 ms
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=114 ms
64 bytes from pypi.python.org (82.94.164.168): icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=113 ms
^C
--- pypi.python.org ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 113.367/113.871/114.678/0.614 ms

:~$ sudo easy_install virtualenv
Searching for virtualenv
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
^Cinterrupted
:~$
```

I can even connect to the site from within Python:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> obj = urllib.urlopen('http://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/')
>>> obj.readlines()[0]
'<html><head><title>Links for virtualenv</title></head><body><h1>Links for virtualenv</h1><a href="../../packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=3daa1f449d5d2ee03099484cecb1c2b7">virtualenv-1.5.1.tar.gz</a><br/>\n'
```

I have had the same result with packages other than `virtualenv`. Is easy_install looking somewhere else for connection information, or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's a problem with `sudo`. If you use `sudo`, the variable `$http_proxy` is unknown in this context.

`sudo -i` opens up a root shell. There you can set the `$http_proxy` variable again and then easy_install works - you don't have to use sudo because you are already superuser.

```
$ sudo -i
# export http_proxy=http://192.168.1.25:80
# easy_install virtualenv
```

Or you can have your actual environment in sudo context and save the "get root step" via:

```
$ sudo -E easy_install virtualenv
```

Comment: Thank you.  Figures that I forget about things like scope when I'm not programming.  I must have set up `http_proxy` in /etc/environment on the other installations where I had no problem.

Comment: BRILLIANT. No guides have this.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than opening up a root shell with `sudo -i` you can run the command

```
$ sudo -E easy_install virtualenv
```

The `-E` switch preserves your current environment.

Comment: Another gotcha is that some sudo-like replacements (e.g. dzdo) refuse to preserve these variables even if you tell them to.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
# export http_proxy=x.x.x.x:YY
# export https_proxy=x.x.x.x:YY
# export ftp_proxy=x.x.x.x:YY
```